# Completeness of wolfram database of graphs

Tags: graphs-and-networks, curated-data

Does the Wolfram database of graphs include *all* connected graphs when the number of vertices is <= 8?

Comment: Look in https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Connectivity_(graph_theory).

Comment: @user64494 That table is for labelled graph, but GraphData does not have isomorphic duplicates.

Answer (score 12):

We can get the number of connected graphs on $k$ nodes that are contained in `GraphData` as follows:

```
Table[Length@GraphData["Connected", k], {k, 1, 8}]
(* {1, 1, 2, 6, 21, 112, 853, 215} *)
```

Let us compare this to the total number of connected unlabelled graphs on $k$ nodes, which is recorded in [OEIS A001349](https://oeis.org/A001349):

```
1, 1, 2, 6, 21, 112, 853, 11117
```

We see that up to 7 nodes, `GraphData` has all of them.  But it only has 215 connected graphs on 8 nodes, while the total number is 11,117.