# How can I get as many graphs as possible?

Tags: graphs-and-networks, curated-data

I badly need data about edges in *all* graphs (or maybe just connected ones will satisfy me --  it depends on further research) on $n$ vertices for as great $n$ as possible. I have already downloaded it up to $n = 8$ from built-in GraphData and wrote in a file, but need more.

[It was already discussed here](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/138072/46316) that GraphData database has complete information for graphs on less or equal than $7$ vertices, which doesn't satisfy me.

I gave a try to old *Combinatorica* package, but even execution of the `

```
Needs["Combinatorica`"]
Table[Length@ListGraphs[k], {k, 1, 8}]
```

took all the CPU resources and about $4$ Gb of RAM, after that I used to abort it, since it was close to the limit of my laptop.

Is there any way how can I get readable for further usage in Wolfram Mathematica data about all graphs (edges in them) with greater than $7$ or $8$ vertices avoiding GraphData and direct calculations with ListGraphs? Maybe it is possible to download it somewhere and convert to appropriate for Wolfram Mathematica format?

Comment: All the source code for `ListGraphs` is down inside the Mathematica tree in `Combinatorica.m`, which is so much better than when it is compiled into the kernel where nobody can inspect it, and is only a handful of lines. Perhaps you could study that code and see if it would be possible to "turn it inside out" to generate graphs one at a time and do your processing as each one is generated.

Comment: What kind of data do you need? In all kind of graphs all kind of edges appear ;-) Why don't you generate all possible graphs from all possible adjacency matrices?

Comment: Brendan McKay gives lists up to 10 nodes [here](http://users.cecs.anu.edu.au/~bdm/data/graphs.html)

Answer (score 3):

[Brendan McKay's nauty suite](http://pallini.di.uniroma1.it/) includes graph generation tools.  [The `geng` program](https://www.mankier.com/1/nauty-geng) can generate all non-isomorphic undirected graphs on $n$ nodes.  The output is in Graph6 format, which Mathematica supports.

I am currently using OS X and I installed nauty using MacPorts (`sudo port install nauty`), which placed it in `/opt/local/bin`.  You will need to replace the paths below with wherever you install nauty yourself. Now I can get a list of graphs on 4 nodes like this:

```
Import["!/opt/local/bin/geng 4", "Graph6"]
```

[image]

If you are patient, you can generate larger sets too:

```
graphs = Import["!/opt/local/bin/geng 8", "Graph6"]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {4.15069, Null} *)

Length[graphs]
(* 12346 *)
```

But be aware that the number of graphs (and the time needed to compute them) will quickly explode.

```
graphs = Import["!/opt/local/bin/geng 9", "Graph6"]; // AbsoluteTiming
(* {105.883, Null} *)

Length[graphs]
(* 274668 *)
```

When you generate larger graphs, you probably do not want to import the entire list at once.  Instead, you can do the following.

This command starts the `geng` program:

```
process = StartProcess[{"/opt/local/bin/geng", "11"}]
```

You do not need to wait until `geng` finishes to start reading the graphs.  You can use `Import[process, {"Graph6", "GraphList", k}]` to read the `k`th graph generated.